# PL/SQL Dynamic SQL in function with single quotation

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql

Below is the Function I need to accomplish.

```
create or replace function GET_FROM_ANY_STD2(TheValue in varchar2, TheTableName in varchar2, TheContext in varchar2)
return varchar2
is GET_FROM_ANY_STD2 varchar2(10000);
begin

select listagg(value0, '@') within group (order by rn) into GET_FROM_ANY_STD2
from (
 execute immediate
       'select levels.column_value rn,
              trim (regexp_substr(TheValue, '[^@]+', 1, levels.column_value)) as did
              from dual t, table(cast(multiset(select level
                                                from dual connect by level <= length(regexp_replace(**TheValue**, '[^@]+')) + 1)
              as sys.odcinumberlist)) levels) t
       left join **TheTableName** d on d.code0 = t.did and d.context =**TheContext**;
       return(GET_FROM_ANY_STD2);'
end;
```

but when I try to execute this, I get several errors.
all balues between double star need to be parameter.
I tries several things, but none succeed :(
I appreaciate any help.
Best Regards,
Murat

Comment: There is no `return` statement. What is it supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is this piece of code supposed to do as returns something you never referenced in your code: `listagg(value0 ...)` - what is `value0`?

Anyway, just to show the way it is supposed to be done, here you go.

Sample table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE thetablename
  2  AS
  3     SELECT '0' code0, 'context' AS context FROM DUAL;

Table created.
```

Function: as you use dynamic SQL, you have to concatenate parameters to the rest of the code. This is ugly, difficult to debug, difficult to read, difficult to write (single quotes issues), you must be aware of possible SQL injection (read about `dbms_assert`).

I tried to keep it as simple as possible by composing the SQL statement in a separate variable (`l_str`) and then just *execute* its result into the `retval`.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_from_any_std2 (TheValue      IN VARCHAR2,
  2                                                TheTableName  IN VARCHAR2,
  3                                                TheContext    IN VARCHAR2)
  4     RETURN VARCHAR2
  5  IS
  6     l_str   VARCHAR2 (10000);
  7     retval  VARCHAR2 (10000);
  8  BEGIN
  9     l_str :=
 10           'WITH
 11        trows
 12        AS
 13           (SELECT t.COLUMN_VALUE rn,
 14                   TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR ( '
 15        || CHR (39)
 16        || TheValue
 17        || CHR (39)
 18        || ',
 19                                        ''[^@]+'',
 20                                        1,
 21                                        t.COLUMN_VALUE)) AS did
 22              FROM DUAL t
 23                   CROSS JOIN
 24                   TABLE (
 25                      CAST (
 26                         MULTISET (
 27                                SELECT LEVEL
 28                                  FROM DUAL
 29                            CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
 30                                         LENGTH (
 31                                            REGEXP_REPLACE ( '
 32        || CHR (39)
 33        || thevalue
 34        || CHR (39)
 35        || ',
 36                                                            ''[^@]+''))
 37                                       + 1)
 38                            AS SYS.odcinumberlist)) t)
 39     SELECT LISTAGG (t.did, ''@'') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t.rn)
 40       FROM trows t
 41            LEFT JOIN '
 42        || TheTableName
 43        || ' d
 44               ON     d.code0 = t.did
 45                  AND d.context = '
 46        || CHR (39)
 47        || TheContext
 48        || CHR (39);
 49
 50     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_str
 51        INTO retval;
 52
 53     RETURN retval;
 54  END;
 55  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> SET VERIFY OFF
SQL>
SQL> SELECT get_from_any_std2 ( '&thevalue', '&thetablename', '&thecontext') result
  2    FROM DUAL;
Enter value for thevalue: 0@abc@def
Enter value for thetablename: thetablename
Enter value for thecontext: context

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0@abc@def

SQL>
```

---

So, yes - it *does something* and *returns something*. I have no idea whether this is what you really wanted, but - now that you know **how** to do it, do it.

Comment: Unfortunately not correct. I have a table called std, and some other lookup tables with same structure.

Comment: The structure is as follows:
create table STD
(
  context            VARCHAR2(30),
  code0              VARCHAR2(3),
  value0             VARCHAR2(254),
  value1             VARCHAR2(254),
  value2             VARCHAR2(254),
  value3             VARCHAR2(254),
  value4             VARCHAR2(254),
  flags              INTEGER,
  upid               VARCHAR2(21),
  upd_cnt            NUMBER(3) default 0 not null,
  id                 NUMBER(10) not null,
  last_modified      DATE,
  last_modified_user VARCHAR2(30),
  create_date        DATE,
  create_user        VARCHAR2(30)
)

Comment: let's say the data for STD table are as follows:
context, code0, value0

"a", "x", "x1"

"a", "y", "y1"

"b", "z", "z2"

"a", "z", "z1"

Comment: main goal is to get the string "x1@z1" when the inputs are; TheValue='a@z', TheTableName = 'STD', TheContext ='a'.

Comment: The main sqp accomplishes the goal, without parametrised table name. That is what I need to accomplish...

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing I'd like to add to what I already wrote. Feel free to improve code I posted.